# how to represent class that contains no methods, only fields?

Tags: c#

My class contains no methods, only several fields, like host, port, labels, channels etc. etc.
I.e. its kind of config.
Should I use regular `Class` for representing configs? I want to make it obvious to reader that this instance is just a container for other values.

**upd** My config is pretty big and comes from xml, so it's a tree.

Comment: Read through this, it should help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Comment: Interesting that the OP made no mention of structs and people immediately determined this to be a "structs vs. class" question. Is that the case?

Comment: If you have too many fields, why you using class, ...? you can put them in config file?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri I need to use fields at runtime. So I read config once and then use it whereever I need.

Comment: @vcsjones: Can you suggest an alternative to classes and structs?

Comment: Why do you think it matters that you communicate to client code that your class contains no non-property methods?  The only facet of a class that clients should care about is what they can do with it.  The internals and implementation details aren't consequential, right?  I honestly don't understand where the need for debate originates - you have a given set of values within a certain scope, so you made them attributes of a class.  Where's the confusion?

Comment: @KendallFrey I can't but probably there are some guidelines at least how to implement such classes, or keywords, or something, that's why I ask question.

Comment: @ValAkkapeddi I just think that `Class` is bad to represent `config`. Configs are pretty simple things...

Comment: Is there going to be multiple of these objects?  How many different classes/methods are going to accept this `class`?  If there's only going to be one of these config objects, maybe use `app.config` / `web.config` instead.

Comment: @Matthew I have only one config so far, but theretically there can be two or more configs... (for example one "real" and one "test" config)

Comment: @javapowered I can only assume you're joking, right? :-)  You have a set of values that you want to unite under a common scope - a common domain class isn't the natural answer that occurs to you?  Why would you implement configurations any other way than by subclassing [ConfigurationElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelement.aspx)?

Comment: @javapowered you can have `release` and `debug` configs with VS2010 and newer.

Comment: @Matthew I already have third-party xml config. I want to use it because if third-party updates file I can just replace it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, most likely you should be using `class`. There are rare case as pointed in other replies to use `struct`.

Name your class "ContainerForConfigurationProperties", than look at the resulting code. If it looks bad - refactor by changing class name till you are happy. Note that you may find that after coming up with good name some properties no longer fit into your class - it may mean that you class actually was container for several sets of properties - refactor by splitting the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a class with public automatic-property getter/setters, then you can easily serialize/deserialize it (say to XML).  Especially if the intent is to be consumed by other readers/developers, then using properties will shield them from changes when building against updated versions of your library.  It also leaves the door open in the future if you want to implement anything in terms of tracking value changes, issuing events, performing validation, or just straight-up debugging with breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it a class, that's fine. It should be obvious what it's supposed to do, hold config info.

You may want to create an Interface in cases where you'll have a number of different config classes. For example, you might have an IConfig interface that has a few properties and then additional interface elements in more config interfaces (IHostConfig, ILabelConfig, etc.) that you can fit together to build your specific classes with a common, understandable, interface.